# REACT NATIVE: How to fetch API JSON data in RN

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, api

I am trying to fetch JSON data from this API: 'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all'
I have tried several times even from official docs, but nothing helped , i am not getting error but nthing shows onn screen

```
 useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json.message))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

   
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
      {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Text>{item.message}  ghbdt </Text>
                      )}
        />
      )}
    </View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are hitting is the return from the API is an object not an array:

`{"message":{"affenpinscher":[],"african":[],"airedale":[]...}}`

To make this work for you you will need to turn the returned data in to an array, if all you are after is the key value and not the values in the arrays then you could just change your `setData` to `setData(Object.keys(json.message));` this will then give you a list of dogs out.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using async and call handleData on an event click or using useEffect as well. Hope this way helps you.

```
async handleData() {
axios.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => setData(json.message))
  .catch((error) => console.error(error))
  .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }
```

Another way maybe you can try passing data in array dependency useEffect[].

Comment: sorry but where should i put it??